# What does correlation filtering actually do?

Tags: computer-vision

[image]

In the slide, $G(i, j)$ is the sum of the values of all these different colours. But what does $F(u, v)*I(i, j)$ represents? And what is $G(i, j)$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G is the output image (on the right side)

F is the filter kernel (the 5x5 image hovering over I)

I is the input image (the image on the left)

So every outputpixel (i,j) is set to value G(i,j) which is calculated by the given formula.
u,v are coordinates within F, so F(u,v) is a value of the filter kernel.
You basically sum up pixel-wise products of values of your input and your filter array.

The Filter is moved across the image and for every pixel you calculate G(i,j) using the only the pixels of I that lie under F. At the end you have a new image I that consists of those calculated values.

Read this for further info:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/CMSC426/Convolution.pdf